# drop-down menus in Flash

Tags: flash, drop-down-menu, sprite, haxe

**What are the common ways of creating drop-down menus for Flash with Haxe?**

I've used a variety of "drop-down" menus:

- drag-and-drop "combo boxes" in C# Forms
- `<select>` in HTML
- UIPickers in iOS

Now I'd like to create something similar in Flash. Note I'm not using Flex per requirements that are out my control.

I'm quite new to Flash. So far it looks like I'll extend Sprite and perhaps use some HTML/CSS for styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://doc.aswing.org/a3/org/aswing/JCheckBox.html (ASwing has HaXe port) or https://github.com/sergey-miryanov/MinimalCompsHX/blob/master/Source/com/bit101/components/ComboBox.hx